# How to write query to get Database version from db file storage in SD

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I know that we have to use PRAGMA user_version;this  query to get db version.
But execSQL not working with this query.How to write this query in android to get db version from .db file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `execSQL` does not allow for the return of values/data. As per :-

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data.
>   [SQLiteDatabase - execSQL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase)

You could use the `getVersion` method which returns the version number as an int. Alternately you could use either the `rawQuery` method that would return a Cursor from which you can extract the value e.g.

```
public int myGetversion() {
    int rv = 0;
    Cursor csr = this.rawQuery("PRAGMA user_version");
    if csr.moveToFirst() {
        rv = csr.getInt(0);
    }
    csr.close;
    return rv;
}
```

- The above assumes encodeding within a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper so **`this`** eqautes to an SQLIteDatabase.
- 0 would be returned in the very unlikely scenario that for some reason the user version could not be extracted.

or you could replicate what `getVersion` itself does utilising the DatabaseUtils `longForQuery` method.

e.g.

```
public int myGetVersion() {
    return ((Long) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(this, "PRAGMA user_version;", null)).intValue();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SQLiteDatabase#getVersion()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getVersion()) which in turn is implemented as:

```
public int getVersion() {
    return ((Long) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(this, "PRAGMA user_version;", null)).intValue();
}
```

`rawQuery()` would generally work too for SQL where you're interested in result rows.